# How to run node.js ES6 file on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, ecmascript-6

Can someone help me run a node.js file that has ES6 features? This is my current workflow:

- Save change in file
- `npm run build` --- builds file to my `src/dist` folder
- `cd` into my `dist` directory
- `node`
- `var file = require('./index.js')`
- `file.someMethod()`

Then when I make a change to my method, I need to repeat all the steps above again.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recompile webpack after changing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499390/how-to-recompile-webpack-after-changing-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need anything if you are not using import/export. Just Install node 8.x and then run `node my_file.js`. Nodejs supports most of the es6 features out of the box.

If you want to use import/export then I would recommend to use typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/. It has compiler TS (statically typed ES6) to ES5.

Oh, and of course both babel and typescript have watcher modules (auto recompiling on file change).

Comment: Hi - I just upgraded to node 8.0.0.. and I verified the version by running `node -v`. However, I'm still getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: Thats what I said, it supports all es6, EXCEPT import/export. I personally use typescript, and recommend you to do the same, but if you dont want, then just use babel.

Comment: I too prefer typescript tbh, but I'm not aware of an easy way to use TS in a repl so I suggested babel-cli purely because I know you can launch it as a repl. A quick google does bring up [this (ts-node)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) though so maybe that would work also.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what `npm run build` actually does in your app. Does it run gulp/grunt? Webpack? Etc. If it's webpack there is a [webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server) that you should look into.

If it's grunt or gulp then you have a custom build chain that you're working with. If all you need is to support es6 features without having to build the project then you could use something simple like [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) and run your file from outside the `dist` directory.

```
$ npm i -g babel-cli
$ babel-node
> var file = require('./index.js');
> file.someMethod()
```

By running `babel-node` you're running the normal node repl but with babel required. Es6 features should now be supported in the repl without needing to be compiled to es5.

---

You may also want to try simply updating to the latest version of node because node 8 has pretty extensive es6 support.